# iphone - not full screen modal

Tags: iphone

At some part of my code I am using this line

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

This works perfectly and pushes a view, coming from bottom, over the current one, covering the last one completely.

I am wondering if there's a way to make it cover just part of screen. Let's say, just the half bottom of the screen...

Is it possible? I have tried to change the controller's view frame but the size kept coming full screen.

thanks.

Comment: for anyone who understands german there is a great tutorial about modal view controllers :-) http://bedifferently.wordpress.com/2011/12/25/modal-view-controller-uimodalpresentationstyle/2011/12/25/modal-view-controller-uimodalpresentationstyle/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using a new view controller modally, you could add a new subview to your existing view, using the same view controller.

You can do the "slide in" animation with something like:

```
[self.view addSubview: newView];

CGRect endFrame = newView.frame; // destination for "slide in" animation
CGRect startFrame = endFrame; // offscreen source

// new view starts off bottom of screen
startFrame.origin.y += self.view.frame.size.height;
self.newImageView.frame = startFrame;

// start the slide up animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];   
    newView.frame = endFrame; // slide in
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a limited fashion with a modal view controller.  Check out the presentation options available under UIModalPresentationStyle in the apple docs.

You will need to be on iOS 3.2 or above to do a modal view controller.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I don't think this gives you the option of non-full-screen on an iPhone ("On iPhone and iPod touch devices, modal view controllers are always presented full-screen, but on iPad devices there are several different presentation options.")

Comment: On iPad I am using popovers but for iPhone my problem is that I am developing for 3.0 and up and I suspect, as David Gelhar said, I will be out of luck.... unless I fake it using a regular view animation.